# How to solve this reccurence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let a,b,c be real numbers. Find the explicit formula for $f_n=af_{n-1}+b$ for $n \ge 1$ and $f_0 = c$

So I rewrote it as $f_n-af_{n-1}-b=0$ which gives the characteristic equation as $x^2-ax-b=0$. The quadratic formula gives roots $x= \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{-2}, \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{-2}$

Then $f_n=P_1(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{-2})^n+P_2(\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{-2})^n$ and using the initial condition $t_0=c$ gives $C=P_1+P_2 \Rightarrow P_1=C-P_2$

So $(C-P_2)(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{-2})^n+P_2(\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{-2})^n$ what next? I tried expanding but that didn't help. I know the answer is something like $cd^n-\frac{b}{a-1}+\frac{bd^n}{a-1}$

Comment: You seem to be trying to use the solution to $f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}$ to solve $f_n=af_{n-1}+b$.

Comment: You characteristic polynomial is wrong, you need to have a homogenous realtion to even use it.

Comment: your difference equation is a first order one. the characteristic equation is invalid in this case

Comment: @TZakrevskiy is it not a homogeneous equation because it has $+b$ at the end?

Comment: @toufik_kh.17 how do you solve first order, just by iteration?

Comment: yes, it's not a homogenous relation because it has terms which are not linear in $f$ (in your case, indeed, because of $+b$). See my answer below with description how deal with such situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=1$, then $f_n=f_0+nb$, otherwise since $f_n=af_{n-1}+b$ we can subtract $\frac{b}{1-a}$ from both sides to get
$$
f_n-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(f_{n-1}-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)
$$
therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
f_n
&=\frac{b}{1-a}+a^n\left(f_0-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)\\
&=a^nf_0+b\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It is not clear to me how you get from $a \ne 1$ to $f_n-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(f_{n-1}-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)$

Comment: @Celeritas: just subtract $\frac{b}{1-a}$ from both sides of the recurrence equation: $b-\frac{b}{1-a}=-a\frac{b}{1-a}$

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: why did you subtract $\frac{b}{1-a}$ from both sides of the equation? It's not like you randomly decided on a fraction to subtract.

Comment: @Celeritas: because I wanted to get the first equation, which shows this is a geometric sequence. I used an unknown (as in Ray's hint) to figure out what to subtract. I just did not show that computation.

Comment: So you subtract $\frac{b}{1-a}$ from both sides but shouldn't that be $f_n-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(f_{n-1}\right)-\frac{b}{1-a}$ not $f_n-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(f_{n-1}-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)$?

Comment: @Celeritas: no, because it is $\color{#C00000}{f_n}-\frac{b}{1-a} =\color{#C00000}{af_{n-1}+b}-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(f_{n-1}-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)$.

Comment: Ok I get it now, on paper I wrote down 3 more steps between $\color{#C00000}{f_n}-\frac{b}{1-a} =\color{#C00000}{af_{n-1}+b}-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(f_{n-1}-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Why not consider this?

$f_n + m = a(f_{n-1} + m) \Longrightarrow (a-1)m=b$

1) $a=1$, simple recurrence $f_n = f_{n-1} + b$, $f_n = bn+c$

2) $a\neq 1$, $m=\frac{b}{a-1}$, $f_n+m = a(f_{n-1}+m)$, geometric sequence $f_n+m=a^n(c+m)$

Hope it is helpful!

Comment: Where does $m$ come from?

Comment: @Celeritas: I think $m=-\frac{b}{1-a}$ as in my answer.

Comment: I believe this is a geometric sequence, not a geometric series (just a terminology difference).

Comment: This is a good hint. I used a similar computation to compute $-\frac{b}{1-a}$ in my answer. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn My typo. Thanks bro!

Comment: @Celeritas $m$ is the trick used here, helping you get the geometric sequence.

Comment: Ok but when you add $m$ to both sides shouldn't it become $f_n+m=af_{n-1}+m$ not $a(f_{n-1}+m)$?

Comment: @Celeritas Actually it not really adding $m$ to both sides, it is a way of illustrating how you interpret the $b$ on the right. By the $m$, I am showing you can regard $b=(a-1)m$ for some $m$ so as to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your approach is false. Your characteristic polynomial would work for the recurrence relation $f_{n+1}=af_n+bf_{n-1}$, but not for your case. You need to have a homogeneous relation for working with that polynomial, which you don't. Therefore, you need first to do a couple modifocations.

You can write
$$  f_{n+2} - f_{n+1 }=a(f_{n+1} - f_{n}),$$
which gives immediately a homogenous version (and now we can use characteristic polynomial!):
$$f_{n+2} = (1+a)f_{n+1 } - af_{n}$$
with a characteristic polynomial $x^2-(1+a)x+a$, its roots are $1$ and $a$.

Suppose that $a\ne 1$, hence, you have $f_n=p_1a^n+p_2$. Now we need to check that the initial relation (non-homogenous):
$$p_1a^{n+1}+p_2=a(p_1a^{n}+p_2)+b,$$
which gives us $p_2=\frac{b}{1-a}$. Now, the initial condition at $n=0$ allows to say that $p_1=c-p_2=c-\frac{b}{1-a}$. We rewrite to get $$f_n =\left(c-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)a^n+\frac{b}{1-a}.$$

Now on to the case $a=1$. In this case the roots of characteristic polynomial are the same, therefore the solutions are $f_n = p_1na^n+p_2 a^n=p_1n+p_2 $. The initial condition gives immediately $p_2=c$.  We check the non-homogenous relation: 
$$p_1(n+1)+c = (p_1n+c)+b$$
or
$$p_1  =    b.$$
Thus, the solution is $$f_n = bn+c.$$

Comment: Interesting idea to convert this to a homogenous equation (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Define $F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} f_z z^n$, and write your recurrence as:
$$
f_{n + 1} = a f_n + b \quad f_0 = c
$$
Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, and recognize:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} f_{n + 1} z^n &= \frac{F(z) - f_0}{z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} b z^n         &= \frac{b}{1 - z}
\end{align}
to get:
$$
\frac{F(z) - c}{z} = a F(z) + \frac{b}{1 - z}
$$
This gives:
$$
F(z) = \frac{c + (c - b) z}{1 - (a + 1) z + a z^2}
     = \frac{b + (a - 1) c}{(a - 1) (1 - a z)} - \frac{b}{(a - 1) (1 - z)}
$$
This is just two geometric series:
$$
f_n = \frac{b + (a - 1) c}{a - 1} \cdot a^n - \frac{b}{a - 1} 
$$
As a check, $f_n = c$.